# Sumif formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which adds two new worsheets ws2 and ws3

The following vlookup formula works fine

```
With ws3.Range("E4:E" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A4," & ws2.Name & "!A:C,3,FALSE)" 
End With
```

But when I want to add another formula to the column F which is excel formula `SUMIF(January!G:G,A:A,January!H:H)` it does not work when I rewrite as follows

```
With ws3.Range("F4:F" & LastRow)
   .Formula = "=SUMIF(" & ws2.Name & " ! G:G, A:A ," & ws2.Name & " !H:H)"
End With
```

I asked the same question in the Mr Excel forum, but have not received a reply yet.

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1048876-vba-adding-formulas-referencing-new-sheet.html

Comment: sumif is expecting a single criterion in the second argument not a range.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sumif is expecting a single criterion in the second argument not a range.

I expect you want your reference to be more like:

```
With ws3.Range("F4:F" & LastRow)
   .Formula = "=SUMIF('" & ws2.Name & "'! G:G, A4,'" & ws2.Name & "'!H:H)"
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much